# How to find entities with empty relationships in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data, entity

I have model with entities: `PBOUser` and `PBOLocation`.
 There is relationship `many to many`. Every user may have a lot of locations and every location may belong to many users.

User and location has its own unique field: `identifier`.

It is very simple to find locations that belongs to a specific user:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY users.identifier == %@", user.identifier)
```

*if any user inside `users` field has identifier same as user.identifier... this is location I am looking for*

But the question is:
**How to find locations that not belong to any user?.** In other words, their `users` field is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the count of the relationship:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "users.@count == 0")
```

Comment: shouldn't be `NSPredicate(format: "users.@count == 0")`?

Comment: My mistake... shouldn't be `NSPredicate(format: "locations.@count == 0")`?

Comment: My answer assumes you are fetching `Locations`, which have a relationship named `users`.  "locations that not belong to any user" are those `locations` where the count of the related `users` is zero.